# Upgrade sencha cmd 4 to cmd 5 and I have the error when execute

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-cmd

I am a app with Sencha touch 2.4.1 + cordova 4.0.0 .

When I compiled with cmd 4 all worked well, but for a error in cmd I had must reinstall the cmd and the only version than I had find is cmd 5. I installed it , and the compiler work fine BUT with a error when I see the result.

> Requested:
>   'http://localhost/popo/lolo/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js
>   seems to have been changed. Attempt to refresh the application?

Somebody know this error?  I find but I don't find the resolution

THANSK!!!!

[image]

Comment: When I build the aplication and go to url localhost the error is  Error evaluating  .... sencha/build/package/app.js

Answer (score 0):

The only way has been, build another projects of cordova and sencha.

Now works all right.

Cristian